# Git not able to fetch remote branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am facing an issue in fetching one remote branch. I can see that in bitbucket, however, I can't see that when I run the `git branch -a` command

Following is the git config. (I have replaced by URL with dummy values)

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://gaurang.shah@bitbucket.abc.com/test.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

**Git command**

```
git fetch release/fix_kerberos_retry_logic
```

**Error Message:**

```
fatal: 'release/fix_kerberos_retry_logic' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**update:**
I am able to clone the branch though

```
git clone -b branch_name repo_url
```

Comment: Is the branch visible if you `git fetch` and then `git branch -a`? Also, you have to specify the remote repository name for the `fetch` command; i.e. `git fetch origin release/fix_kerberos_retry_logic`. Or just `git fetch`, to fetch all branches from all remotes.

Answer (score 4):

The first argument of [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) is the name of the remote to fetch from.

Assuming that `release/fix_kerberos_retry_logic` is the name of a remote branch that is present on the `origin` remote, your command should be:

```
git fetch origin release/fix_kerberos_retry_logic
```